# UNQL DataStorage

Tags: nosql, couchbase, unql

I have installed UNQL in my system and tried to run the below Queries in UNQL client

```
CREATE COLLECTION adc;

INSERT INTO adc 12345;

SELECT FROM adc;
```

but i am not getting the result can any one tell me what went wrong in the above queries.

Regards
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

You should create or open the database first and you forgot VALUE term:

```
> .new my.db
> CREATE COLLECTION adc;
> INSERT INTO adc VALUE 12345;
> SELECT FROM adc;
12345
```